# Sigma Sum Properties

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

My Probability and Statistics teacher wrote the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8keUx.jpg

[image]

How can I prove such step?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Expand $(x_i-\bar x)^2$ and simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline x)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\overline x)\cdot (x_i-\overline x) $

=$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i^2-2x_i\cdot \overline x+\overline x^2)$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2- \sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_i\cdot \overline x+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline x^2$

$2,\overline x$ and $\overline x^2$ are constants. Thus they can be put in front of the sigma signs.

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2- 2\cdot \overline x\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+ \overline x^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1$

- $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1=n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=n\cdot \overline x$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2- 2\cdot \overline x\cdot n\cdot \overline x+ n\cdot \overline x^2 $

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2- 2\cdot n\cdot  \overline x^2+n\cdot \overline x^2 $

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-  n\cdot  \overline x^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 - 2 x_i \bar{x} +\bar{x}^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2) - \sum_{i=1}^n (2 x_i \bar{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{x}^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\bar{x} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i  + n\bar{x}^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2n\bar{x}^2  + n\bar{x}^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - n\bar{x}^2
\end{align}$$